# Spark [Scala]: Order between transform and transformSchema methods in a customised Transformer

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The `transform` method does the transformation on a DataFrame, if the schema doesn't change then we return `schema` within `transformSchema`; if it does change, we need to update the `transfromSchema` method's body. My question has two folds:

1. In what order Spark uses these methods?
2. We do transform the DataFrame, is there a shortcut to get the transformed DataFrame and getting its schema for the `transformShema` method, such that we don't manually declare?

Comment: `transform` is used to chain methods. However I do not have the memory to manually change the schema. Do you have a sample code to show your point? I don't get it

Comment: @BlueSheepToken for example lets say I have a transformer, where within the transform method I change all the type of columns into IntegerType. So within the transformSchema, I also need to say what will be the transformedSchema (all int cols). Then here, what will be the order? What is the use of transformedSchema method? I have to have it because we extend Spark's Transformer.